# Ruby blocks and optional arguments: {|x=1|}

Tags: ruby

Why is `x=1` an optional argument here:

```
proc {|x=1|}.arity                  # => 0
```

Looking at the docs (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-i-arity), I don't see anything that explains why `|x=1|` means the parameter is optional whereas `|x|` means it's not optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|x=1|` declares a block argument with a default value.  If the argument has a default value, that means it can be omitted and the default is used instead.  Any argument that can be omitted, is by definition, optional.

Though it looks like ruby 1.9 allows you omit any argument in a block, and that will simply be set to `nil`.

So you can for the result you want if you simply don't use block argument defaults, and do it manually instead.

```
# Your proc
proc { |x=1| puts x }.arity #=> 0
proc { |x=1| puts x }.call  #=> 1

# suggested edit
proc { |x| x ||= 1; puts x }.arity #=> 1
proc { |x| x ||= 1; puts x }.call  #=> 1
```